# Redis Connection failure exception received when trying to run Spring-cloud-data-flow server in docker container

Tags: redis, spring-cloud-dataflow

```
: Failed to perform redis operation.

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:204) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:348) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:129) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:92) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:79) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:194) [spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.analytics.retry.RedisRetryTemplate.access$101(RedisRetryTemplate.java:34) [spring-analytics-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.analytics.retry.RedisRetryTemplate$1.doWithRetry(RedisRetryTemplate.java:70) ~[spring-analytics-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:286) [spring-retry-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:179) [spring-retry-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.analytics.retry.RedisRetryTemplate.execute(RedisRetryTemplate.java:63) [spring-analytics-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the SCDF server receives requests to fetch data from analytics repository (which is redis by default) and you don't have `Redis` running as expected by the SCDF server. 
One such case would be accessing the UI analytics tab.

You can also disable `anlaytics` features by setting `spring.cloud.dataflow.features.analytics-enabled` to `false`.

This is something related to https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1636.

Comment: i intend to use analytics on this setup. am running redis ,kafka, scdf local  all in respective docker containers linked to a common network. dont want to disable analytics feature . let me know what specific settings to be taken care of so that redis and scdf connection is resolved.

Comment: All you need for redis is the Redis connection factory settings via typical Spring Boot Redis connection properties with the prefix `spring.redis` such as spring.redis.host, spring.redis.port properties.